# Saving charts as images when converting xls to Google Sheets - Google Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a standard script from the Internet which converts xls to Google Sheets. The charts in the output file got converted to images which is a good thing, I needed charts to be saved as images as the original xls have specific formatting I would like to preserve but the problem is that they look awful - the color shaded, the font dropped to a very small size, the legend floats somewhere. Ultimately I need to have these images to be saved in Google Slides. So, what I was thinking is to find a way (1) to save images from xls and saves directly in Google slides or (2) to save images from xls to Google Sheets but somehow preserve the original formatting and then, run another code that saves the images to the target Slides. Interestingly, I have not found any mention of people complaining of the loss of the chart formatting.

```
function convertExceltoGoogleSpreadsheet2(fileName) {

  try {

    fileName = fileName || "name";

    var excelFile = DriveApp.getFilesByName(fileName).next();
    var fileId = excelFile.getId();
    var folderId = Drive.Files.get(fileId).parents[0].id;  
    var blob = excelFile.getBlob();
    var resource = {
      title: excelFile.getName().replace(/.xlsx?/, ""),
      key: fileId,
      parents: [{id: 'id'}]
    };
    Drive.Files.insert(resource, blob, {
      convert: true
    });

  } catch (f) {
    Logger.log(f.toString());
  }

}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, in the current stage, Google Apps Script cannot directly read and edit XLS format. So ``to save images from xls`` cannot be achieved using Google Apps Script. I apologize for this situation.

Comment: Hi Tanaike, thank you for the response! What would be your suggestion? Maybe save xls as html, too, and then, grab the image from the folder?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize my comment was not useful for your situation. About ``save xls as html``, how do you convert this?

Comment: Well, I actually didn't know if it is feasible, I just thought what I would do w/o automation. Maybe it is possible to somehow make adjustments to images while converting from xls to Sheets?

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. At first, I commented ``Unfortunately, in the current stage, Google Apps Script cannot directly read and edit XLS format.``. This mean that Google Apps Script cannot be directly retrieve the parsed values from XLS data. By this, values cannot be retrieved from XLS data while XLS format is converted to Google Spreadsheet. I apologize for this situation.

Comment: No, no, you explained it well! I just stubbornly pushed my idea! Thank you

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm sorry that your issue was not resolved. In the current stage, when users read and write Microsoft Docs with Google Apps Script and Google APIs, at first, Microsoft Docs data is required to be converted to Google Docs data. By this, users can read and write  to the data. It seems that this is the specification.